# Wie sagt man "this feature is not supported" auf Deutsch?

Tags: phrase, vocabulary

Ich bin nicht sicher ob immer supported = unterstützt

Mein Vorschlag wäre

> EDITED: "Dieses Feature oder diese Funktion wird nicht unterstützt"

aber ich glaube das ist näher zu

> "This feature is not **being** supported"

Ist unterstützen gültig nur wenn wir über physikalische Unterstützung sprechen? Oder geht das auch für z.B. Software?

Danke

Comment: 'wird nicht unterstützt' is simply a passive construction, just like 'is not supported'; in any case not "progressive" (i.e. being supported). Also, it's *das* Feature.

Comment: Ist es ein undokumentiertes Feature, das die Software zwar besitzt, für das aber kein Anwendersupport geleistet wird, oder ist es eine in einem Standard beschriebene Funktion, welche in der Software noch nicht implementiert ist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prinzipiell ist

> Diese**s** Feature wird nicht unterstützt.

oder

> Diese Funktion wird nicht unterstützt.

korrekt.

Auch für Software, es ist eigentlich immer gleich zu *supported*.

Wenn du mir den genauen Kontext zeigst, kann ich dir noch genau erklären welches der beiden am besten geeignet ist.

Answer (score 2):

Um die Unklarheit zwischen »this feature is not supported« und »this feature is not *being* supported« aufzuklären: Dieser Dualismus existiert in dieser Form im Deutschen nicht. Zwar existieren einige Variationen, wie eine Verlaufsform gebildet werden kann – Beispiele wären »das wird *gerade/derzeit* nicht unterstützt« oder ähnliche – aber im Großen und Ganzen kennt das Deutsche keine Verlaufsform wie es das Englische kennt. Oftmals ist es nur eine Frage des Kontexts, ob eine Aussage als Verlaufsform gedeutet werden soll oder nicht. Das heißt, dass sowohl die Variante mit *being* als auch die Variante ohne *being* mit dem gleichen Satz übersetzt werden können:

> Dieses Feature<sup>[1]</sup> wird nicht unterstützt.

Wenn das englische Verb *to support* ist, ist im Softwarebereich grundsätzlich *unterstützen* eine gute Übersetzung, egal ob es sich um Kundenservice oder Programmfunktionalitäten handelt.

---

[1]: Eine Anekdote eines akademischen Direktors im Ruhestand der LMU München:

> Wissen Sie übrigens, wie ich *Feature* schreibe? F-i-e-t-s-c-h-e-r.

Comment: I'm saving that anecdote for later :)

Comment: VIelen Dank für die Erklärung @Jan